# Kubernetes service doesn't properly configure environment variables

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-container

I have two applications both running in containers, but are deployed separately on the same host and namespace.

The main application is talking to the supporting application using REST APIs. For that it needs a host and a port for the supporting application. I have a service running to expose the supporting application.

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Service
> metadata:
>   name: my-app
>   namespace: my-ns
>   labels:
>     app: my-app
> spec:
>   ports:
>   - port: 80
>     protocol: TCP
>     targetPort: <container port>
>   selector:
>     app: my-app
> ```

For the main application I have a values.yaml and a deployment.yaml with environment variables for supporting application host and port.

values.yaml snippet:

> ```
> my-app-host: my-app
> my-app-port: 80
> ```

deployment.yaml snippet:

> ```
>  env:
>         - name: my-app-host
>           value: '{{ index .Values "my-app-host" }}'
>         - name: my-app-port
>           value: {{ index .Values "my-app-port" }}
> ```

When I'm running the main application, I'm seeing that it is trying to reach the supporting application on an empty host, like so: http://:my-app-port/REST-API-endpoint

I suspect that it is not pulling either host or port properly. Although the port looks correct, when I tried to change it to a dummy number in the service.yaml (above), it was still showing the correct port.

I would appreciate any help correcting my service set up.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Is it `http://:my-app-port/REST-API-endpoint` or `http://my-app-port/REST-API-endpoint`? Difference is `:` before `my-app-port`

Comment: @Chris I think the point is that the **host** is missing before the `:`, and that the actual value for `my-app-port` is not substituted.

Comment: Correct, it's the former - the host is missing, so what I'm seeing is http://:my-app-port/REST-API-endpoint

Comment: Are you using helm?

Comment: If you are using helm, then it should be `{{ .Values.my-app-host }}`, same for the other

Comment: Agree, the problem with that is that my env variables names have hyphens in them,  and helm has a restriction on hyphens use.. I found the "index" solution on stack overflow. I might have to change the variable names in the application itself then.

Comment: I am using helm for the main application and just deployment.yaml and service.yaml for the supporting application